# Need to simplify multiple Select queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is the structure of my existing SQL query :

```
SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT *, 'A' AS Status FROM Table1
    WHERE Field1 NOT IN 
    (
    SELECT Field1 FROM Table2 WHERE Field 1 = 'val' AND ...
    )

    UNION

    SELECT *, 'B' AS Status FROM Table1
    WHERE Field1 IN 
    (
    SELECT Field1 FROM Table2 WHERE Field 1 = 'val' AND ...
    )

) AS Result
```

Here I'm selecting two sets of data from a table and assigning **two different values** (A & B) for the `Status` column and Union both sets in to one as Result.

Problem with this method is, it needs to duplicate the inner select query `SELECT Field1 FROM Table2 WHERE Field 1 = 'val' AND ...` (my original sql query is bit complex than the shown above)

How can I rewrite this as a single Select query? Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply move the WHERE condition to a CASE expression, like this:

```
SELECT
  *,
  CASE 
    WHEN Field1 IN (
      SELECT Field1 FROM Table2 WHERE Field1 = 'val' AND ...
    )
    THEN 'B'
    ELSE 'A'
  END AS Status
FROM Table1
;
```

You could also use a LEFT JOIN method like others suggested, but if `Table2` produces duplicates for the specified filter, you might get duplicates in the output as well. To avoid that, you would probably need to use a derived table that only returns distinct values, something like this:

```
SELECT
  t1.*,
  CASE 
    WHEN t2.Field1 IS NULL THEN 'A'
    ELSE 'B'
  END AS Status
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT Field1 FROM Table2 WHERE Field1 = 'val' AND ...
) t2
  ON t1.Field1 = t2.Field2
;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `LEFT JOIN` on this,

```
SELECT  a.*,
        CASE WHEN b.field1 IS NULL
            THEN 'A'
            ELSE 'B'
        END AS Status
FROM    table1 a
        LEFT JOIN table2 b
            ON a.field1 = b.field1 AND
                b.field1 = 'VAL'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below query, which works if there is only one condition of `Field1=’val’` on `Table2`. If there are multiple where conditions, then go for `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT 
    *,
    (CASE WHEN Field1='val' THEN 'B' ELSE 'A' END) AS Status 
FROM 
    Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

U can achieve this by using `LEFT JOIN` and `CASE` as follows

```
SELECT  a.*,
    (CASE b.Field1
           WHEN 'Val' 
           THEN 'B' ELSE 'A' END) as status
FROM  Table1 a LEFT JOIN Table2 b ON a.field1 =b.field1
```

If multiple conditions are there for status try the following one

```
SELECT  a.*,
    (CASE 
           WHEN (SELECT COUNT(Field1) 
                 FROM Table2 
                 WHERE field1 =a.field1 AND Field 1 ='val' AND ...) >0
           THEN 'B' ELSE 'A' END) as status
FROM  Table1 a LEFT JOIN Table2 b ON a.field1 =b.field1
```